# How to work with UTM and multiple zones

Tags: utm, sharpmap

I'm totally a newbie with geo tools. I'm using Sharpmap as I'm working with C#.

I have a map where I can put an item on a UTM Location with E,N Zone and number. So the item appears on the desired position.

The problem comes when I want to move the item to a new position. So, for example, I want to increase easting by 2000 meters.

How can I calculate if my item has crossed to a new zone? The easting ranges differ from equator to the poles, am I right? Is there a way to calculate easting ranges of a certain zone?

What is the best way to work with location points in different zones -- for example, to calculate distance between them?

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to re-project either your coordinates or datasets so that they are in the a common UTM zone. That way there is no need to know when you have crossed bounds. Then you can measure points.

Alternatively, it is possible to calculate a zone based on coordinates. You can do this with PROJ.4 or you can find a C# algorithm or lib for UTM if you look.